# Enable GridGain Control Center to Ignite cluster deployed in Google Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, gridgain

I deployed ignite 2.10.0 in google cloud kubernetes. It is working properly. Now I need to enable control center to it. [1] provides instructions to deploy control agent backend and frontend. After deploying them I created account and need to connect cluster to it. [2] given download option but not provide information to configure libraries with kubernetes.

Please help.

[1]. https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/installation/kubernetes

[2]. https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/connect-ignite-cluster

Answer (score 2):

Default ignite docker image doesn't contain control center files. I created new docker image using ignite docker image.

Following is the Dockerfile

```
FROM apacheignite/ignite:2.10.0
WORKDIR /opt/ignite
RUN wget https://www.gridgain.com/media/control-center-agent/control-center-agent-2.9.0.1.zip
RUN unzip control-center-agent-2.9.0.1.zip
RUN cp -r libs/control-center-agent/ apache-ignite/libs/control-center-agent/
RUN cp bin/* apache-ignite/bin/
RUN rm -r bin/
RUN rm -r libs/
RUN rm control-center-agent-2.9.0.1.zip
```

or take docker image from [1]

[1]. https://hub.docker.com/r/nuwansameera/ignite-with-control-center/

Use this docker image to create Deployment or Statefulset